# vif, multicollinearity, Error in as.vector(y) - mean(y) : non-numeric argument to binary operator,

Tags: r

***Please help! By using vif for multicollinearity come those errors:***

> vif (M1)
>   **Error in as.vector(y) - mean(y) : non-numeric argument to binary operator**

In addition: Warning message:
In `mean.default(y)` : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

My script:

```
library(lmtest) 
M1 <- lm(y ~ x + x1 + x2,           
          data = Mydata)
summary(M1)
library(VIF)
vif (M1)
```

Comment: You are loading the wrong package. If you want to calculate Variance Inflation Factors I suggest you use package `car`. `VIF::vif` implements VIF-regression, which is a different beast.

Comment: Thank you very much!! How to load this package? Could you please write a code.

Comment: Dear Roland! Thank you a lot!!!!!!! It was really wrong package! Now it works! A lot of success in R and in general also to you! :))))

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following steps:

```
install.packages("car") 
library(car)
vif(M1)
```

It works for me